# Python - Pdf created in landscape format : How to change in portrait?

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a program in my company which generate PDF in landscape format. (I can't change print settings)
I want to get the pdf in a portrait format without rotate the text.
I tried with PyPdF, changing MediaBox Settings. It's almost good... But datas are centered . I want them to be at the top of the page.
How can i get that ?
Thanks for your help !

Here's my Python script :

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import datetime
    import os
    import sys
    import PyPDF2
    
    pdf_in = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in, strict=False)
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
    page.mediaBox.setLowerLeft((0,0))
    page.mediaBox.setLowerRight((595.3,0))
    page.mediaBox.setUpperLeft((0,841.9))
    page.mediaBox.setUpperRight((595.3,841.9))
    pdf_writer.addPage(page)
    pdf_out = open('test2.pdf', 'wb')
    pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)
    pdf_out.close()
    pdf_in.close()
```

Comment: Thank your answer, but it 's still centered... :/

Comment: That is absolutely what i was looking for ! Thank you KJ !
I've imported Transformation class from PyPDF and applied translation on the page. It works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
import PyPDF2

pdf_in = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in, strict=False)
pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

# add this part in your code
for pagenum in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(pagenum)
    # you can add another condition here if you choose to rotate only certain pages
    # input the rotation degree here *rotateClockwise(**degree**)*
    page.rotateClockwise(90)
    pdf_writer.addPage(page)

pdf_writer.addPage(page)
pdf_out = open('test2.pdf', 'wb')
pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)
pdf_out.close()
pdf_in.close()
```

Comment: Your proposition rotates the page, i have text and a table that i want to be unchanged.